# OpenVPN LAN to LAN

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, openvpn, local-area-network

We would like to setup OpenVPN so that we are able to see our devices just like we are connected over a lan switch.

The "lan switch" is our server. When we connect to the VPN network we want to get a ip address over dhcp and see each other like "directly connected over an lan switch". To keep it short, we would like to play games over VPN.

But we WONT connect the complete Lan network and there nearby connected devices to it or even internet. In this case we just want to connect the pcs that use the OpenVPN client over "a virtual wire".

We got that far that we are able to get an ip address and ping the server using tun. But we are not able to see other devices connected.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Id found the solution

https://debianforum.de/forum/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=94415
Problem was, that the data from the clients wasnt routed to the gateway. Just add:

```
push "route-gateway 10.8.0.1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.8.0.1"
```

With that addition a config is pushed to the clients. Then they will know that they have to push there data to the "gateway".

Comment: Pleas translate this into english.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `client-to-client` option to the openvpn server config file. If specified, the VPN server will internally route packages between connected clients. This way the clients will see each other, but not the network around the others.